# New alert Dialog not showing ANDROID STUDIO

Tags: java, android, sdk

```html
07-11 20:44:43.348 12614-12614/com.karanvir.search E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                     Process: com.karanvir.search, PID: 12614
                                                                     java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:355)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:324)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:285)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDialog.setContentView(AppCompatDialog.java:83)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:225)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:257)
                                                                         at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:578)
                                                                         at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:314)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:955)
                                                                         at com.karanvir.search.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:143)
                                                                         at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:3204)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:408)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:113)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:113)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar$2.onMenuItemClick(ToolbarActionBar.java:69)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar$1.onMenuItemClick(Toolbar.java:206)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView$MenuBuilderCallback.onMenuItemSelected(ActionMenuView.java:776)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:822)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:156)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:969)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopup.onItemClick(MenuPopup.java:127)
                                                                         at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:345)
                                                                         at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1547)
                                                                         at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3821)
                                                                         at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:5841)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                                                                     
                                                                     
                                                                     --------- beginning of system
07-11 20:44:43.388 752-13505/? E/android.os.Debug: ro.product_ship = true
07-11 20:44:43.388 752-13505/? E/android.os.Debug: ro.debug_level = 0x4f4c
07-11 20:44:43.388 752-13505/? E/android.os.Debug: sys.mobilecare.preload = false
07-11 20:44:43.428 13515-13515/? E/Zygote: v2
07-11 20:44:43.428 13515-13515/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
07-11 20:44:49.228 28799-28830/? E/ContactsProvider_EventLog: Flush buffer to file cnt : 10 size : 7Kb duration : 153ms lastUpdatedAfter : 19910 ms mFlush_time_threasold : 2000 mCurrentSize : 3670
```

My new alert dialog wont show when i click the option for it in my settings, I get a full crash on my app instead. I am very confused on what to do here, can someone please help me. Im new to development also, so sorry if this is a nooby question. Thank you for reading

**ANDROID STUDIO**

```html
package com.karanvir.search;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Random rn;

    AutoCompleteTextView searchBar;
    public static String urlGlobal;
    TextView con;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        searchBar=(AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView);
        Button button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        con=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

         rn= new Random();
        final SharedPreferences perf= this.getSharedPreferences("com.karanvir.shareprefernces", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
//setting up an alert

        if(perf==null){


            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.alert_dark_frame)
                    .setTitle("How to use")
                    .setMessage("Search what you want in the search bar! after we will choose a search engine our computer will recommend. After that you can change the search engine using the options menu in the right hand corner")
                    //then need to set a onclick listener with our positive button
                    .setPositiveButton("eng", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "its done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            //where we would right our code where the user would confirm us to do
                            perf.edit().putString("choiceOne","eng").apply();


                        }
                        //25165012725


                    })

                    .setNegativeButton("fren", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            perf.edit().putString("choiceOne","fre").apply();


                        }
                    })
                    .show();
        }








    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings4) {
            Intent intentGoogle= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Main2Activity.class);
            startActivity(intentGoogle);



            return true;
        } else if(id ==R.id.action_settings2){
            Intent intentGoogle= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Yahoo.class);
            startActivity(intentGoogle);


            return true;

        }else if (id==R.id.action_settings3){
            Intent intentGoogle= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intentGoogle);


            return true;

        }else if(id==R.id.action_settings1){

                new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
                        .setTitle("About")
                        .setMessage(".....")
                        .show();
                return true;

        }
        else if (id==R.id.action_settings5){
            new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
                    .setTitle("About")
                    .setMessage("This app intercha")
                    .show();
            return true;

        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    public void jump(View view){
        //intnet changing target of our code
urlGlobal=searchBar.getText().toString();
        Log.i("stuff",urlGlobal);




        int pageJump = rn.nextInt(3)+1;
        if (pageJump==1){
            //google
            Intent intentGoogle= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Main2Activity.class);
            startActivity(intentGoogle);
        } else if (pageJump==2){
            //YAHOO
            Intent intentGoogle= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Yahoo.class);
            startActivity(intentGoogle);

        } else if(pageJump==3){
            //GOOGLE
            Intent intentGoogle= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Main2Activity.class);
            startActivity(intentGoogle);

        }
        try {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you invoked AlertDialog.Builder() , you should also invoke .create()
then call the method dialog.show()

Answer (score 0):

the code is like this

```
AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder()
        .setMessage("hello world")
        .setPositiveButton("yes",new OnClickLisenter(Dialog dialog(something)))
        .setXXX()
        .create();

   dialog.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

put this code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Random rn;

    AutoCompleteTextView searchBar;
    public static String urlGlobal;
    TextView con;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        searchBar=(AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView);
        Button button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        con=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

         rn= new Random();
        final SharedPreferences perf= this.getSharedPreferences("com.karanvir.shareprefernces", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
//setting up an alert

        if(perf==null){


            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.alert_dark_frame)
                    .setTitle("How to use")
                    .setMessage("Search what you want in the search bar! after we will choose a search engine our computer will recommend. After that you can change the search engine using the options menu in the right hand corner")
                    //then need to set a onclick listener with our positive button
                    .setPositiveButton("eng", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "its done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            //where we would right our code where the user would confirm us to do
                            perf.edit().putString("choiceOne","eng").apply();


                        }
                        //25165012725


                    })

                    .setNegativeButton("fren", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            perf.edit().putString("choiceOne","fre").apply();


                        }
                    })
                    .show();
        }








    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings4) {
            Intent intentGoogle= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Main2Activity.class);
            startActivity(intentGoogle);



            return true;
        } else if(id ==R.id.action_settings2){
            Intent intentGoogle= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Yahoo.class);
            startActivity(intentGoogle);


            return true;

        }else if (id==R.id.action_settings3){
            Intent intentGoogle= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intentGoogle);


            return true;

        }else if(id==R.id.action_settings1){

                new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
                        .setTitle("About")
                        .setMessage(".....")
                        .show();
                return true;

        }
        else if (id==R.id.action_settings5){
            new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
                    .setTitle("About")
                    .setMessage("This app intercha")
                    .show();
            return true;

        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    public void jump(View view){
        //intnet changing target of our code
urlGlobal=searchBar.getText().toString();
        Log.i("stuff",urlGlobal);




        int pageJump = rn.nextInt(3)+1;
        if (pageJump==1){
            //google
            Intent intentGoogle= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Main2Activity.class);
            startActivity(intentGoogle);
        } else if (pageJump==2){
            //YAHOO
            Intent intentGoogle= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Yahoo.class);
            startActivity(intentGoogle);

        } else if(pageJump==3){
            //GOOGLE
            Intent intentGoogle= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Main2Activity.class);
            startActivity(intentGoogle);

        }
        try {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: change AppCompatActivity to activity

Answer (score 0):

In styles.xml change your style to

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```